# Is an instance of System.Enum type stored on the heap

Tags: f#, enums

Consider a F# Enum declaration:

```
type MyEnum =
  | A = 1
  | B = 2
```

I can now make a value of type MyEnum:

```
let enumValue1 = MyEnum.A
```

The value enumValue1 is inferred to have type MyEnum.

However I can also make an instance of my Enum type:

```
let enumValue2 = new MyEnum()
```

The value enumValue2 is also of type MyEnum.

I read that Enum types are wrappers over integral types and that Enums are stored on the stack.

However in the above code snippet I instantiate my Enum type. This instance is stored on the heap ?

In essence I'm confused whether Enums are stored on the stack or heap (or maybe both depending on the situation) ?

The trick doesn't work:

```
typeof<MyEnum>.BaseType = typeof<System.ValueType>
```

... because Enums are of type System.Enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think your confusion about `new` comes from C++. There, you can write either something like `MyEnum e = MyEnum();` or `MyEnum* e = new MyEnum();`, where each means something different. There is no such distinction in C#, it doesn't matter whether you create the value using `new` or not.

> I read […] that Enums are stored on the stack.

That's gross oversimplification, and I would say that it's wrong, when said like this. `Enum`s can be stored on the stack, yes, but they can also be stored on the heap or in registers. And in most cases, it shouldn't matter to you where exactly are they stored.

> However in the above code snippet I instantiate my Enum type. This instance is stored on the heap?

Like I said above, it doesn't matter that you used `new`. Where exactly is a value stored depends on circumstances.

If the variable is actually a simple local:

```
let a = MyEnum.A
printfn "%A" a
```

Then it will be stored on the stack or in registers.

But you can also use the same syntax to define a field of a type:

```
type Test() =
    let a = MyEnum.A
    
    member this.A
        with get() = a
    
printfn "%A" (Test().A)
```

In this case, `Test` is a .Net class, which is a reference type, so `a` will be stored on the heap inside memory allocated for some `Test` object.

But there are also less obvious cases. For example:

```
let a = MyEnum.A

let getA() = a  
    
printfn "%A" (getA())
```

In this case, the local `a` won't be stored *anywhere*, because the code for `getA()` will be optimized to return `MyEnum.A` directly.

```
let a = (fun() -> MyEnum.A)()

let getA() = a  
    
printfn "%A" (getA())
```

Making the initialization for `a` more complicated means the previous optimization won't be used and `a` is now stored in a static field (those are usually stored in a special section of the heap).

---

So, as you can see, where exactly will the value be stored can be quite complicated and compiler-specific. And you shouldn't care about it, unless you're performing microoptimizations. Also, it certainly doesn't have anything to do with `new`.

> The trick doesn't work:
>
> ```
> typeof<MyEnum>.BaseType = typeof<System.ValueType>
> ```
>
> … because Enums are of type System.Enum

But `Enum` itself is derived from `ValueType`, so this returns `true`:

```
typeof<MyEnum>.BaseType.BaseType = typeof<System.ValueType>
```

Although the fact that `System.Enum` and `System.ValueType` themselves are reference types makes the situation even more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword in .NET is different from C++'s `new` keyword (which allocates memory from the heap).  In .NET, `new` just creates a new instance of an object and invokes its constructor (if it has one).  Whether that new object is on the heap or the stack will generally depend on whether it's a value type or a reference type, not whether you used `new` or not.

It can be noted that `int`s and other primitives also have 0-argument constructors:

```
new Int16()
```

Using `new` on an `Enum` or a primitive type will just create an instance of that type with its default value (generally 0).

Comment: Few corrections: code like `new Int16()` won't actually call any constructor, `Int16` even doesn't have any constructors. But with value types, you can use `new` without parameters to get the default value.

Comment: And where an object is allocated doesn't depend on `new`, but it's also not as simple as you make it to be.

Comment: @svick Thank you for those corrections. I've corrected the part about the constructors, but I'm afraid I don't know enough to be able to correct the second part.  If you could tell all of us either in your own answer or in the comments, I'm sure Nicolas and myself would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate them like `new MyEnum()` because in .NET, all value types are required to have a parameterless, public constructor. In the case of enums, this is like casting 0 to your enum type:

```
> LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue<_,MyEnum> 0;;
val it : MyEnum = 0
```

You can also check that enums are in fact value types:

```
> typeof<MyEnum>.IsSubclassOf typeof<System.ValueType>;;
val it : bool = true
```

Comment: @svick I removed that part. I wouldn't say it's entirely incorrect though -- enums can be stored directly on the VES (Partition I, Chapter 12, ECMA-335, 5th ed.) so they'll be stored in machine registers in the JIT-compiled code, and enum-typed local variables will be allocated/stored in the stack frame of the JIT-compiled method. Enums will only be "allocated" in the heap when they're allocated as part of some other structure, like an array -- and even then, it's really that structure which is heap-allocated (not the enum itself).

Comment: Saying that they *can* be stored on the stack, under certain circumstances, is not the same as saying that they *are*. Also, in these questions, “stack” usually means the native stack, not the CIL evaluation stack. And “local” usually means local variable in F#/C#, not in CIL.

Comment: Also, it's inaccurate to say that `new MyEnum()` calls constructor, there is no parameterless `.ctor()` method on value types. `new MyEnum()` simply returns the default value of the type.

Comment: @svick - as long as we're picking nits, value types in .NET may have parameterless ctors (though C# and F# won't allow you to write one).  See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/12/10/value-types-and-parameterless-constructors.aspx.

Comment: @kvb Yeah, I know, that's why I said that there are no such constructors (meaning in BCL and reasonable code), not that there can't be any. Although I thought C# or F# won't call that constructor even if it exists, which is apparently incorrect.